# Converting MySQL Query to Yii CDbCriteria

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have two table which is named

1. new_tbl_master_siteid -> model : SiteID
2. app_tbl_ict_dapot_genset -> model : genset

and i have a mysql query like this

```
SELECT A.siteid, B.type, B.status_operations, B.status
FROM new_tbl_master_siteid as A
LEFT JOIN app_tbl_ict_dapot_genset as B
ON A.siteid = B.siteid
```

Where i want to left join the **siteid** column

I was thinking of modifying the CdbCriteria on the genset model, how can i do this so the dataprovider of the genset gridview can also use the column from the SiteID model?

**Criteria from the genset model**

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('siteid',$this->siteid,true);
        $criteria->compare('merk',$this->merk,true);
        $criteria->compare('type',$this->type,true);
        $criteria->compare('capacity',$this->capacity,true);
        $criteria->compare('kapasitas_tangki',$this->kapasitas_tangki,true);
        $criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true);
        $criteria->compare('status_operations',$this->status_operations,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
```

==================

Here is the relation below

```
class genset extends CActiveRecord
.....
public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
         return array(
            'siteids'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'SiteID','siteid'),
        );
    }
....

public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('siteid',$this->siteid,true);
        $criteria->compare('merk',$this->merk,true);
        $criteria->compare('type',$this->type,true);
        $criteria->compare('capacity',$this->capacity,true);
        $criteria->compare('kapasitas_tangki',$this->kapasitas_tangki,true);
        $criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true);
        $criteria->compare('status_operations',$this->status_operations,true);
        $criteria->with = array('siteids.rtp');
        $criteria->compare('siteids.rtp',$this->rtp,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

and the siteid class

```
class SiteID extends CActiveRecord
.....
public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'gensets'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'genset', 'siteid'),   
        );
    }
```

But i got an error

```
Relation "rtp" is not defined in active record class "SiteID".
```

rtp is a column from the siteid model

Comment: provide relation between your 2 tables, is it one to many, many to many etc ?

Answer (score 1):

Yii way to do this is thru Relations e g you should add relation to the joined table into your model (if it is not already there) and then you can directly access to related model's properties, for example if SiteID object is $model and  relation's name is 'genset', you can get genset's status like this:  $model->genset->status

Comment: can you give me an example? 
i am trying to parse status into the gridview, which the gridview calls 'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to do is create relation between models that can be done like this :

```
public function relations()
{
        return array(
            'genset'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'genset', 'siteid'),
        );
}
```

in model class. Once relations are defined in both models modify your criteria to pull result with join using `->with`

```
$criteria->with = array('genset');
```

and you are ready to go. but make sure you define relation in both the models.